# how to solve issue when keyboard is getting displayed, keyboard hides the tab bar

Tags: iphone

when keyboard is getting displayed, keyboard hides the tab bar. How to change the position for keyboard? I want to do similar to skype app calling screen.

I want to display simple keyboard on my tab bar from bottom i have found lots of links and explanation on adding toolbar & tab bar on top of keyboard please help to solve this ASAP i need it urgently to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can't move up the keyboard. And even if you could, you shouldn't, as it would be very uncomfortable typing when everything's shifted up like 50px due to the tab bar below it.

Comment: So is there any way to achieve this i need it guys because it's a need of my application

Comment: As I said, no, you can't move up the default iPhone OS keyboard. The only thing you can do is to build your own keyboard view. But before you do this, are you really, really sure this feature is necessary for your app to function correctly? Because, as I said, it makes typing really uncomfortable...